# Indexes in strings

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
str = "something"
str[0, 1] #=> "s"
str[0, 2] #=> "so"
str[3, 4] #=> "ethi"
str[2, 3] #=> "meth"
```

I can't see logic in this. What is returned by this double indexes?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)? It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 3):

`str[2,3]` is `"met"`. In this form it is `str[zero_based_start_position, number_of_characters]`

See [ruby documentation on String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)